# Do we know of any niggunim that date back to the Beit Hamikdash?

Tags: history, music

I have heard that some niggunim date back to the times of the Beit Hamikdash and I cant remember which ones! What I do remember is that they used (what we would call) a 4/4 time signature and major/minor keys.

Any references would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have heard that the tune used in many shuls (every one I've ever been to, although I've only been to Ashkenazi shuls for Yom Kippur) for Kol Nidre dates back to the Temple.

Comment: While some melodies are sometimes called *mi-sinai*, I would be astonished if any are earlier than medieval, when the earliest melodies known to music historians date.